# ensure one type of user cannot log in as another type of user django

Tags: python-3.x, django

In Django, how can I make sure that one type of user cannot log in as another type of user? For example, if there are two types of users on my website, teachers and students, teachers should not be able to use their credentials to log in as a student and vice versa.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Comment: Do you have legacy databases with two different databases (or tables) depending on user type? Are your users already created in the Django auth app?

Comment: Hi Mimo! I have edited my question to show what I have in my models.py. And yes I am importing the User from django.contrib.auth.models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by using [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

let us say only students should access the registration page, so you can create user_passes_function which returns True if user is student otherwise False and decorate the studen_registation view as shown in the snippet code below

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def student_check(user):
    try:
        get_object_or_404(Student, user=user)
    except:
        return False
     else:
      return True

@user_passes_test(student_check)
def student_registration(request):
```

Comment: hi Husam, thank you! Does that mean I need to create a boolean variable like is_student and is_teacher as one of the fields in both classes?

Comment: I have updated the answer with proper solution after reviewing your models, you can check

Comment: sounds good, thank you! is this function in models.py for Student or does this go in views.py

Comment: It goes in view ( not in model) , its used as decorator for view function , if my answer help you,  please don't forget to vote!!

Comment: yes, it did, just upvoted, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome 